# Cannot import mean from statistics

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to import statistics module in python. It's giving me an error message when i execute the program.

**Here is my code:**

```
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
ys = np.array([2,8,5,0,5,7,3,6])
def best_fit_line(xs ,ys):
    m = ( ((mean(xs)* mean(ys))- mean(xs*ys)) /
          (mean(xs)*mean(xs))-(mean(xs*xs)))
    return m
m = best_fit_line(xs,ys)
```

**The error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kudzai/Documents/Machine Learning/LinearRegAlg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from statistics import mean
ImportError: No module named statistics
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/statistics.html) was added in Python 3.4. Perhaps you're using an older Python version.

If you can't upgrade for whatever reason, you can also just use `numpy`'s `mean` function: `np.mean(xs)` etc. For `numpy` arrays, it's probably faster too.